# How to do currying function in Python

Tags: python

Is this a right example of currying? The task was to create a function of 4 args that returns the following: y = x1**2 + sqrt(x2) + x3/(x1 + x2) + c. So the 4 arguments are x1, x2, x3, c. This is my code:

```
import math  

def func(x1, x2, x3, c):                
    return x1 ** 2 + math.sqrt(x2) + x3/(x1 + x2) + c     


example = func(5, 16, 7, 1)         
print(example)                      



def func1(x1=5):                    
    def func2(x2):                  
        def func3(x3=7):            
            def func4(c):           
                print(x1 ** 2 + math.sqrt(x2) + x3 / (x1 + x2) + c)     

            return func4            

        return func3                

    return func2                    


func1()(16)()(1)
```

Can you explain how to do the currying function correctly, if my solution is incorrect?

Comment: I don't see an error in your code. Are you simply asking whether or not your code is correct or are you sure that your code is incorrect?

Comment: @IceRevenge I’m just asking, because my teacher underestimated me for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I thought this must be a dup, but other similar questions I could find were more specialized. OK, this is currying as described in textbooks and tutorials:

```
import math  

def func(x1, x2, x3, c):                    
    return x1 ** 2 + math.sqrt(x2) + x3/(x1 + x2) + c    

v = func(5, 16, 7, 1)          
print(v)          

# now with currying:

def curry4(f):
    def f1(x1):
        def f2(x2):
            def f3(x3):
                def f4(x4):
                    return f(x1, x2, x3, x4) 
                return f4
            return f3
        return f2
    return f1

cfunc = curry4(func)
cv = cfunc(5)(16)(7)(1)
print(cv)
```

To understand it you must know how closures work. The inner `f4` function has access to all four required values through "free variables".

You could think of these two lines:

```
cfunc = curry4(func)
cv = cfunc(5)(16)(7)(1)
```

as:

```
f1 = curry4(func)
f2 = f1(5)   # and free variable x1=5
f3 = f2(16)  # and free variable x2=16
f4 = f3(7)   # etc
cv = f4(1)
```